# How to get vm arguments from inside of groovy (gradle)?

Tags: spring, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

At startup pass this `-Dname=value`

and then in your code you should use

```
value=System.getProperty("name");
```

to get that value.

I use it in java, but how to get the same value in groove?

In my case I run spring boot with gradle and I need read this value in gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.properties['name']`:

```
task myTask() {
    println System.properties['name']
}
```

Result:

```
> ./gradlew -Dname=hello myTask
hello
:myTask UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.73 secs
```